# table sorter not working for Apex:inputcheckbox Column

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I am using a table sorter to sort all the column.All columns are working fine except one column "Rush Request" which has apex:inputcheckbox tag.The column needs to be sortable, i.e. when the column header is clicked, all the checkboxes that are checked needs to bubble up or bubble down.Why its not working correctly.Please Suggest.

Below is my VF Page

```
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'jquery.tablesorter.min.js')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'themes/blue/style.css')}"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();    
    $j(document).ready(function () {
    $j("[id$=pendingMilestones]").tablesorter();

    });

  //some other unrelated js
    function reInitializeTableSorter() {
        $j("[id$=details]").tablesorter();
    }


</script>

    <apex:form id="theform" >  
     <div style="overflow:auto;height:500px">
     <!-- ******* Section Of Pending milestones whose actual recieved date is not null  ********   -->  
        <apex:pageBlock id="pb1" title="Pending Milestones"> 
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>

          <apex:outputPanel id="myTable" >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">      
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="pendingMilestones" value="{!displayList}" var="wrap" rendered="{!DisplayList.size>0}"  styleClass="tablesorter" headerClass="header">
                    <apex:column headerValue="PSS Opportunity #">
                        <apex:outputtext styleClass="header" value="{!wrap.field10}"/>                                 
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Status">
                        <apex:outputtext styleClass="header" value="{!wrap.field11}"/>                                 
                    </apex:column>                   
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Rush Request">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrap.field13}" styleClass="header" disabled="true" id="checkbox1"/>
                    </apex:column> 
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:outputText style="font-style:italic" value="No records to display." rendered="{!DisplayList.size=0}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection> 
           </apex:outputPanel> 

        </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: See the accepted answer to. [Jquery Tablesorter - sort by column having <input> elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912957/jquery-tablesorter-sort-by-column-having-input-elements).

Comment: When i am using the <input type =checkbox> instead of <apex:inputcheckbox>, the table show all checkbox as unchecked by default.somehow value="{!wrap.field13}" is not working.Dont know whats the issue

Comment: Keep the `apex:inputcheckbox`; the idea to add a hidden span just before that that the sort sees.

Comment: i tried keeping the apex:inputcheckbox; with the span.Still not got the result.I guess i am not able to get the id of the checkbox in the jquery

Comment: @KeithC do i need to change the jquery too as i am using apex:inputcheckbox

Comment: Suggest you use your browser's "Inspect" feature to check the exact HTML emitted and modify the jQuery accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table sorter compares the HTML node value. One thing you can do is add a hidden `<apex:outputText` just before the checkbox, and add the same value as checkbox. This will be used to sort the column.

```
<apex:column headerValue="Rush Request">
    <apex:outputText value="{!wrap.field13}" style="display:none;" />
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrap.field13}" styleClass="header" disabled="true" id="checkbox1"/>
</apex:column>
```

If you want to sort the table after selecting/de-selecting checkboxes, you have to do something like this. On the click of the checkbox, you have to update the value of `<apex:outputText` also.

```
    $j(document).ready(function () {
        $j("[id$=pendingMilestones]").tablesorter();
        $j("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
            if ($j(this).is(":checked")) { 
                //alert("Checked");
                $j(this).prev().html("true");
            } else {
                //alert("UnChecked");
                $j(this).prev().html("false");
            }
        });
    });
```

This Stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912957/jquery-tablesorter-sort-by-column-having-input-elements) will give more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not working

Comment: What error you are getting in JavaScript console?

Comment: no error.Even the alerts are not getting called.I am not changing the checkboxes.I am just rendering the existing checkbox from the record

Comment: I guess we cannot use change function as the checkbox that i am displaying are disabled

Comment: Thanks a lot .I got it to work.Just adding the <apex:outputText value="{!wrap.field13}" style="display:none;" /> solved the problem.table sorter did the rest

Comment: Please update your answer accordingly.

Comment: @Samir If this answer has solved your question you can use the check mark next to it to mark it as such. That will help others who are looking at it to locate the accepted solution.

Comment: already done that Saroj